# Flex 4.5 - how do you detect screen size to center an image on a mobile device?

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript, flex4, mxml, flex4.5

Tried `stage.stageWidth` and `stageHeight` on `applicationComplete`, but for some reason the actual numbers returned do not seem to be accurate - the image always appears off-centered (stageWidth/2 - imageWidth/2).

How do you determine the mobile device's actual screen size, to center an object?

Comment: I would gladly checkbox the "right answer" when appropriate, but many of my past questions haven't been answered yet. :-(

Comment: Well, if you take the time to look into these questions, you'd see that the right answer hasn't been provided yet. I know there are some users here who value points over helping others, but I just don't feel it's right to give people free points for an answer that doesn't work.

Comment: You're more than welcome to answer your own questions, and select it as such, if now have a solution.  Such an approach would help your select rate.

Comment: Well, if I could figure it out or "google it up," chances are I would not be asking...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you tried:

```
    popUp.width = FlexGlobals.topLevelApplication.width - 40; //popup - leave side edges
    popUp.height = FlexGlobals.topLevelApplication.height - 40; //popup - leave top + bottom edges

    popUp.x = FlexGlobals.topLevelApplication.width/2 - popUp.width/2; //popup x coord
    popUp.y = FlexGlobals.topLevelApplication.height/2 - popUp.height/2; //popup y coord
```

Comment: Syntax Error: "Access of undefined properties, FlexGlobals" Flash Builder 4.5 ... I put that in appComplete in place of the stage.stageWidth's and such.

Comment: No, put it into a function called SizeMe() and call that function to resize once the popup has been invoked. Is it a popup with popupmanager?

Comment: Well, this is on mobile, so I am just trying to get the device screen resolution.

Comment: You don't need the screen resolution to center the image. The code I posted works on mobile. Let's say it's a popup, then when you call popUp, put this code in a function of the component that calls it.

Comment: Why don't you post the code of your application if you need more help.

Comment: Well, for sanity check, I did an empty application that just has a button to `trace(FlexGlobals.topLevelApplication.width);` when clicked on. I still get the Access of undefined properties error.

Comment: Update: it works with `import mx.core.FlexGlobals` - for some reason, ctrl-shift-O did not import that automatically and had to google up to find it was a missing import

Comment: Yeah, copy-pasting code will run into that problem, and FB 4.5 doesn't support the crtl-shift-O import thing as far as I can tell. I've tried it but it's never worked. Glad you got it working. Cheers.